# digits sum of a number (c)

Tags: c, sum

I need to find the sum of the digits of a number with five digits. For example, the sum of the digits of the number `3709` is `3 + 7 + 0 + 9 = 19`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum;
    char digit_1, digit_2, digit_3, digit_4, digit_5;
    printf("Plase enter a five digit number\n");
    scanf("%c,%c,%c,%c,%c", &digit_1, &digit_2, &digit_3, &digit_4, &digit_5);
    sum = digit_1 + digit_2 + digit_3 + digit_4 + digit_5;
    printf("the sum of the digits is: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
plase enter a five digit number                                       
3709                                                                  
the sum of the digits is 51
```

For some reason it doesn't show to correct answer and i can't seem to find whats wrong.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Post your code as a text in the question.

Comment: You are taking `char` type data instead of `int`

Comment: As a general rule, avoid posting pictures of text in the question. Always better to copy the raw text if possible.

Comment: @suvojit_007 that is fine, problem is he is adding ascii values instead of decimal.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I guess his approach is totally wrong. In this problem, only one variable is enough to get the digit sum of a number. I don't know why is he taking char type variables to store the inputs separately.

Comment: Try `scanf("%c%c%c%c%c", ...)`. With your argument you would have to enter in the console `0,3,7,0,9`. Also it is always better to initialize variables with a value, like `digit_1 = 0`.

Comment: @suvojit_007 That might be his requirement to work with `char`. Why are you insisting to use `int`?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Because `int`s are the logical way of storing numbers

Comment: `digit_x` -> `(digit_x - '0')`

Comment: @kiranBiradar this problem could be solved easily by changing the data-type if we follow the OPs method

Comment: @suvojit_007 I Agree. But first we need to tell why OP is facing the issue with `char`.

Comment: `3709` is not a five-digit number and so your computer makes something up.

Comment: @zoids3 consider using `%s` rather than `%c` means take input as whole string not consider it as character wise. Also `manoliar` answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

This works for many digits;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,digit,sum=0;  
    printf("Please gine a positive integer");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n>0)
    {
        digit=n%10;
        sum=sum+digit;
        n=n/10;     
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: Sure! Gives interesting results in release builds. I got 27 for the digit sum of `a`.

Comment: @Swordfish I do not understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: `n` is uninitialized and you don't check the return value of `scanf()` for errors.

Comment: @Swordfish Let him do the rest. I gave him the algorithm and it works.

Comment: @Swordfish `n` is initialized by the `scanf` and no need to check return value of `scanf` for toy programs.

Comment: @Jabberwocky "`n` is initialized by the `scanf`" Maybe. Maybe not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: When "toying" around to understand how `scanf()` & Friends work, it very well made sense to inspect their result.

Comment: Although correct, I feel this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is

your `scanf` needs `,` separated inputs

```
scanf("%c,%c,%c,%c,%c", ...)
```

Hence when you enter 3709 only `digit1` will be read and rest will be omitted by `scanf`. You can check the return value of `scanf` to verify.

and  ASCII value of `3` is `51` thus you are getting `51` as output.

---

Try this

```
scanf("%c%c%c%c", &digit_1 ,&digit_2 ,&digit_3 ,&digit_4 );

int sum = (digit_1 -'0')+(digit_2 -'0')+(digit_3 -'0')+(digit_4 -'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

[*By intention not a complete answer, but way to long for a comment*]

A general rule applies: In case you feel a function fails to do what it should: Take a look at its documentation to learn if it would return any completion/error state. Here: Consult the value the `scanf()` function ***returns***.

Verbatim from [`scanf()`s docs](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4p3):

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Also during development it makes sense to add some debug output, to see what is really going on.

So your code could look like this:

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_* macros */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum;
    char digit_1, digit_2, digit_3, digit_4, digit_5;
    printf("Please enter a five digit number\n");
    int result = scanf("%c,%c,%c,%c,%c", &digit_1, &digit_2, &digit_3, &digit_4, &digit_5);

    if (EOF == result)
    {
      if (ferror(stdin))
      {
        perror("scanf() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      result = 0;
    }

    if (5 > result)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "To few input: Should be %d, but is %d\n", 5, result);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("printing as char: %c, %c, %c, %c, %c\n", digit_1, digit_2, digit_3, digit_4, digit_5);
    printf("printing as int: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", digit_1, digit_2, digit_3, digit_4, digit_5);
#endif

    sum = digit_1 + digit_2 + digit_3 + digit_4 + digit_5;
    printf("the sum of the digits is: %d", sum);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile this with (most) all warnings on:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -DDEBUG main.c -g -o main
```

To fix the final error I leave to you. If done then just remove `-DDEBUG` from the compile options, which would exclude the (hopefully) enlightening `printf`s. ;)

The lesson learned may be: Checking for errors and logging is debugging for free.

Answer (score -1):

```
***Generalized program for any n digit integer!***
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num,digit=0,i,temp,sum=0,rem;
  printf("Enter the number:\n");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  temp=num;
  while(num!=0)
  {
    num=num/10;
    digit++;
    rem=temp%10;
    temp=temp/10;
    sum=sum+rem;
  }
  printf("It is a %d digit number.\n",digit);
  sum=abs(sum);
  printf("The sum of the digits is %d.\n",sum);
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: same answer as given above