# 64 Bit digitsum (C) [Feel Free to edit my English]

Tags: c, 64-bit, sum-of-digits

This is part of my assignment, but I don't know why the output is not correct. Help?

> ```
> /**
>  * Create a function called digitsum that takes an long integer (64                     bits) and
>  * sums the value of each of its digits. i.e. the number 316 should sum to
>  * 3+1+6 or 10. Return the sum as the value of the function.
>  * Hints:
>  * - If the number is negative, make it positive before anything else.
>  * - n % 10 will give you the value of the first digit.
>  * - n / 10 will shift the integer to the right one digit.
>  * - You're done summing when n is zero.
>  */
> ```

Example input/output:

> ```
>  * ./p2 316
>  * num = 316, sum = 10
>  * ./p2 -98374534984535
>  * num = -98374534984535, sum = 77
>  */
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int digitsum(int n){ //first try using function
    if (n % 10)
        return digitsum == n % 10;
    else if (n / 10)
        return digitsum == n / 10; 
    else     
        return 0;  //done summing when n is zero.
}

 // Read down in the comments and do **NOT** modify main below.


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int64_t n;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <int>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    n = atoll(argv[1]);

    printf("num = %ld, sum = %d\n", n, digitsum(n));
    return 0;
}
```

When I use gcc to compile, and it is only show the output "sum is 310" instead of "sum is 10"? I am new to C programming and I'm still studying..

Comment: What loop? like While(if[statement])?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889863/digits-sum-of-a-number-c/52890141#52890141 and build your function.

Comment: Please explain (to yourself and everybody else) what digitsum`()` does, line by line. Think of the example 316 first, then try to abstract to other numbers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of `int digitsum(int n)` is wrong.

You should add each digits in loop, like the follow `code` :

```
int digitsum(int64_t n){ //first try using function
    int ret = 0;
    if (n < 0)
        n = -n;
    while (n != 0) {
        ret += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return ret;  //done summing when n is zero.
}
```

Comment: The point of the function is to do it recursively. It just fails

Comment: p2:
-1.0 output of program (p2) is not correct for input '98374534984535':
------ Yours: ------
num = 98374534984535, sum = 40
---- Reference: ----
num = 98374534984535, sum = 77
--------------------

Comment: @MikeODell I fix it use `int64_t`

Answer (score 0):

Think of a base case for recursion, if your number is 0 you should just return 0, else you get your last digit with `n % 10` and then call your function again to process the other digits except the last one `digitsum(n / 10)`:

```
long long digitsum(long long n) { // I assume n is non-negative
    if (n == 0) return 0;   // terminal case

    return n % 10 + digitsum(n / 10);
}
```